# How can I implement a custom blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I am doing a research project which requires me to implement a blockchain with `pBFT` consensus algorithm. The blockchain would be very simple - A client should be able to send 2 values, the validators or secondary miners would verify the value by checking the blockchain, i.e. previous verified values. If, the value is reasonably close than it would add it to the blockchain by creating a new block. I am thinking of using the `Hyperledger Sawtooth`, because it has `pBFT` algorithm. Please suggest a starting point. I am reading the sawtooth docs but could not implement my version of the blockchain. Any resource would be helpful.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

If your research is purely into consensus algorithms and you want to customize or write your own, PyEVM allows pluggable consensus algorithms.

[You can find more information in this old discussion](https://ethresear.ch/t/clients-with-pluggable-proof-of-work-consensus-algorithms/5632).

If you want to implement your own blockchain for research purposes you can take any of open source implementations of current Ethereum nodes and use them as a starting point. You will find them in various programming languages: Go, Rust, Java, etc.

If your goal is to roll out a private/permission blockchain you can use one of Ethereum permissioned implementations. Then your problem becomes a simple software and server deployment problem.

Comment: How can I use [this](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/app_developers_guide/docker_test_network.html) for my own blockchain, i.e. how can I edit the existing block structure etc

Comment: Actually my application is in `heathcare` so, no need of blockchains involving cryptocurrency as transaction or blocks. I just want to see how the `pBFT` consensus will run with our given data.

Comment: If there no need of blocks, then I suggest you use a distributed database with transaction chaining like https://www.bigchaindb.com/ Before engaging in the project, I would sugget you check the clarity and sanity of the business goals, unless you are a consultant that is paid by the hour.